Movie/TV show based around time and clocks involving kids
So I'm remembering that ages ago (probably in the early to mid 90's) I was watching either a TV show or a movie. It involved children/teenagers moving into a different world/alternate reality that was run on a clock timer. I believe they had to return to the normal world when the clock (a big futuristic looking grandfather clock) otherwise they'd be trapped in the alternate world or something similar.
I also vaguely remember there being some sort of person in the alternate world who would help the children and some villains there as well.
The alternate world they went into (from what i remember) was a city environment but very closed in, lots of walkways between buildings, almost claustrophobic and I think it may have had a red/orange tinge to those scenes but i'm not 100%.
That time frame of early to mid 90's may also be incorrect but I definitely wouldn't say it was later than 2000.

Was it animated or live action?

live action, sorry, should have said that in description.

Maybe it is Finders Keepers (aka The Finder), an australian TV show from the early 90's that matches your description.

Brilliant stuff mate, thank you so much! I found it on youtube, as soon as I saw the clock with the weird figure coming out the top, i knew it was correct. Thanks again!

Sounds like Jumanji, but it was based on an ancient board game which worked like a clock time, and not a real clock timer.

Not Jumanji either, no jungle involved or creatures in that manner. The alternate reality they were transferred into was a sort of city environment but very closed in, almost claustrophobic, it may have also had different colours, red/orange based but i'm not sure of that. thanks for the repsonse though :) (i might add that info into original question if i can).

There is also Little Monsters - the boy (Fred Savage, America's greatest actor for you Family guy fans lol) travels to the monster world under his bed, but has to return otherwise he turns into a monster himself.

Thanks for the reply, unfortunately not what I was looking for but I appreciate the effort :)

Sounds like it could have been the movie Sucker Punch and the man inside Scott Glenn.  
The girls are in a brothel masquerading as an orphanage, and the alternate world is induced from the girls performing a dance and is about them attempting to accomplish some aspect of their escape plan.

Thanks for the response, unfortunately it isn't Sucker Punch. Definately a film I enjoy a lot, this was far earlier than that movie was released. Thanks again though :)

You might want to post alternative possibilities as additional answers in order to give the OP and others the ability to judge (and accept) each answer individually.

HA, I actually thought it would be frowned upon to post multiple answers, hence the edit ... will move to own answer.

@WayneWeibel Identify-questions and their rather exact 0/1-answers are a perfect use case for multiple answers, though.
